# Android on Youtube SERVICE_MISSING error message

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Hai i have done the same application with my json .. The problem in the videoView i am getting on emulator is "An error occurred while initializing the youtube player .. 
Note :Internet Permission in manifest is given

I tried to trace the error

```
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider player, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason){

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String errorMessage = errorReason.toString();

Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

The error result is SERVICE_MISSING

Hope i will get the solution from you.

Comment: Try to check out here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your device/emulator is **probably missing the YouTube application** or, if installed, **it is too old** (must be 4.2.16 or greater).

Comment: or Android 11 is used - I have YouTube app installed but still the same issue, prior 30 API everything works fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631893/youtube-api-oninitializationfailure-service-missing-on-android-11-sdk-30?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

> create a device in emulator that must contain **google api**  for using google services. It means you have not implemented google api in your devices.

Comment: on Android 11 it still doesn't work, I have YouTube app installed but still the same issue, prior 30 API everything works fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631893/youtube-api-oninitializationfailure-service-missing-on-android-11-sdk-30?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers for me the problem was with youtube app ,As i checked with mobile the app worked perfectly.. So it is must to have youTube application on device

Answer (score -1):

Problem is clear you have missed to Internet permission add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

Emulator does not contain play services so you will get error because of that also

Comment: I think you don't read question carefully his already mention added internet permission.

Comment: my bad 
you have to have the youtube app on the device/emulator or 
maybe, it seems to developer key problem. sample DEVELOPER_KEY key that located in DeveloperKey.java will be not work. first, register a new developer key. (https://code.google.com/apis/console) then, replace this with a valid key.

Comment: Thanks for the answers for me the problem was with youtube app ,As i checked with mobile the app worked perfectly.. So it is must to have youTube application on device